# get_pages can't load pages with custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development

I built a one page theme and I use `get_pages()` to load all pages in `front-pages.php`, but I can't load pages with a custom post type. This is my code in `front-pages.php`:

```
$pages = get_pages( array( 
    'sort_order'  => 'ASC', 
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order' 
) );
foreach ( $pages as $page_data ) {
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $page_data->post_content );
    $title = $page_data->post_title;
    echo " <article class='hs-content' id='section".$page_data->menu_order."'>";
    echo "<span class='sec-icon fa fa-home'></span>";
    echo "<div class='hs-inner'>";
    echo "<span class='before-title'>.0".$page_data->menu_order."</span>";
    echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
    echo $content;
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</article>";
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the post type has `hierarchical` set to `true`.

Comment: @jdp : can you explain why "heirarchical" is important?

Comment: @jdp : Yes 'hierarchical' => true

Comment: @s_ha_dum, because if it's not set to true, then WordPress treats the post type like a "post", not a "page". The function docs mention that hierarchical must be true for this function to work: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: I don't see where the docs say that @jdp, and besides, `'hierarchical' => 1` is in the default parameters for the function: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L4418

Comment: It's right at the top of the page.

"This function can also retrieve other post types using the 'post_type' parameter, but the type must be hierarchical like pages, or the function will return false."

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get WordPress to return content from multiple post types with that function call? e.g. pages and custom_post_type content?

If so, you should switch to `get_posts` and specify the post types as an array:

```
$pages = get_posts([
  'post_type' => ['page', 'custom-post-type']
]);
```

Comment: it's doesn't work , any idea instaed of get-posts or get-pages to load all pages in one ???